# How do I send user input through AJAX to Django REST API and return result after function API calculation?

Tags: python, django, ajax, api, rest

I want to learn creating RESTful API's and having AJAX communicating between the backend and frontend, and would like to do it using Python.

I know Python pretty well but have troubles to understand the structure and flow of web applications and how F/E and B/E communicate with each other. Due to this, I would like my website to communicate with my backend RESTful API using AJAX (for educational purposes only.

### My example application

With his in mind, I want to create a simple web application (website) that counts the number of occurrences of a word in a larger text area that users put in. The sequential use case will be:

1. User (client) enters a word to be examined in a textfield: ***"Hello"*** *(input="text")*
2. User (client) enters one or many paragraphs to look
   into: ***"Hello my name is Charles"*** *(input="textarea")*
3. User (client) presses "Submit"-button
4. User (client) receives an updated text (asynchronously) with the number of occurrences of his word in the entered paragraph(s): ***"The word 'Hello' occurred 1 time in your text!"*** 

   (asynchronously modified

   tag)

### My problem and questions

The website is done with two fields and one button. Now here's my problem:

- **How does the AJAX integration and workflow work?** AJAX grab those inputs from the respective fields, send them
  to my REST API (that presumably have the function to count the
  words), and get a response back with the results, to then be shown to
  the user asynchronously?
- **Should I design my Django REST API with class-based views or function-based views?** I really don't need a model to be saved to quickly return the number of occurrences of a word in the given text...

I have my frontend ready from simple HTML5 and CSS3 templates. I can make it work using vanilla JavaScript. But I would like to learn the flow from having AJAX communicating between the F/E and B/E and also learn how to create RESTful API's using Python.

Any help is appreciated! Sorry for the long post. Feel free to ask more if something's unsure of what I mean and I'll explain.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding. Basically, you need to make a request (from js code) to your server (you can use 'fetch API' https://javascript.info/fetch), wait for the response, and do whatever you want with it. For the backend part - I would use class-based views, but for starting you can use function-based ones. Follow the DRF tutorial here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/.

You will probably define a Serializer with two fields (matching the HTML form), and return a response like `{'count': 5}`. Then you can show the message to the user using JS.